# puppet variable overriding fails

Tags: puppet

I am a newbie on puppet and met some issues as subject, googled for some time but failed with an matched answer.
Mys issues is as:

I defined global variables $puppetserver in /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp as below:

```
case $domain {
    /domain2/:{
    $puppetserver = "puppetserver2"
    include migrate
    }
    default:{
    $puppetserver = "puppetserver3"
    }
}
```

in node definition of the servers in domain2
in manifests/labs/domain2/nodes.pp

```
node 'server1.domain2.com' {
    $puppetserver = "puppetserver3"
 }
```

the migrate module is used for puppet migration,  got from internet as below:

in modules/migrate/manifests/config.pp

```
class migrate::config  {
  if $puppetserver == undef {
    fail('You must define the targeted Puppet master to perform the migration')
  } 

  augeas { 'puppet.conf.migrate':
    context => '/files/etc/puppet/puppet.conf/main',
    changes => [
       "set server $puppetserver",
]
}

}
```

Since the node 'server1.domain2.com' can match the domain2 setting in site.pp, so it applies the migrate module,  it should get the 'puppetserver3' for $puppetserver defined in node block and then be updated in '/etc/puppet/puppet.conf' by the Augeas, but actual result is : it is updated as puppetserver2 which was defined in site.pp.
I cannot figure out why overriding is not working. Can you kindly help to check what's wrong?

And as a test:

When I tried to move the 'include migrate' module from site.pp to node 'server1.domain2.com' {} block of nodes.pp, 
it can work as expected.

Comment: You have this `/domain2/:{    $puppetserver = "puppetserver2" ...` Is that what you intend?  It isn't clear, because you say `server1.domain2.com .. should get the 'puppetserver3`.  Is that a typo in your actual code, or a typo in what you have posted here?

Comment: @Zoredache, yes, what I like to realize is  all servers in domain 2 get  $puppetserver  as "puppetserver2" , except the server1.domain2.com should get the 'puppetserver3 which is defined in the node block, but it isnot as expected